# Selecting by date in Umbraco v5

Tags: razor, umbraco

Can someone advise where I am going wrong with this:

```
var results = CurrentPage.Children.Where("raceDate >= DateTime.Now").OrderBy("raceDate");
```

Within Umbraco v5.1 RC I'm trying to create a collection of items with the date today or after but getting the following error:

```
Operator '>' incompatible with operand types 'Object' and 'DateTime'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something ***like*** this (not tested):

ults = CurrentPage.Children.Where("raceDate >= @0", DateTime.Now).OrderBy("raceDate");

The way you have it written, the datetime.now is not going to get substituted into the where clause.